# offline package installation failing R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install some packages to R in order to run my project. Although it runs fine in R `3.3.1`. I moved the project to the company's cluster which runs R `2.15.1`. There are no compatibility issues here since as is stated [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DrugVsDisease.html) The package can be run on `2.10 and above`.
For the code below:

```
if (!require("DrugVsDisease")) {
    install.packages("R_packages/DrugVsDisease_2.14.0.tar.gz", type="source", repos = NULL)
    suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library(DrugVsDisease)))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in install.packages("R_packages/DrugVsDiseasedata_1.10.0.tar.gz",  : 
  unable to install packages
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘DrugVsDiseasedata’
```

Which makes no sense, since it runs smoothly on my personal workstation which runs `R 3.3.1`

Comment: You need to add  `repo=NULL`.

Comment: @42 I did that. No luck.

Comment: It's `repos = NULL`

Comment: @G Gamba please look at the code above...

Comment: @GGamba. There's no ellipsis before that argument in the Usage, so exact spelling should not be needed. The file `DrugVsDiseasedata_1.10.0.tar.gz` cannot be found in that location. Probably not the full path.   .... To Jack: Post the results of `list.files("R_packages", patt="gz")` as well as OS information.